# Window.location in the sucess of the ajax call is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My route -

```
    routes.MapRoute(
     name: "SupplyChainPressureSocialResults",
     url: "supply-chain-pressure/results/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "SupplyChainPressure", action = "Results" }
     );
```

controller Method-

```
//GET:/supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult/{id}
public ActionResult ScptResult(int resultid)
{
   // do something
    return View();
}
```

ajax cal -

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: configMap.sitePath + "api/Quiz/" + quizResponse.quizId,
                    data: JSON.stringify(quizResponse),
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location.href = configMap.sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult' + data.data.quizInstanceID;
                    },
```

But for some reason the redirection is not happening. Can someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was missing /

it should be -

```
 window.location.href = configMap.sitePath + 'supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult/' + data.data.quizInstanceID;
```

I had missed '/' at the end.

Comment: All your urls are static, so they might break in production

Answer (score 0):

The place you are redirecting to doesn't match your route. Your route is looking for:
`supply-chain-pressure/results/{id}`

But you are redirecting to:

`supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult/{id}`

Your route will never match because you are passing in `ScptResult` instead of `results`

What you want to do is change your route definition to this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "SupplyChainPressureSocialResults",
url: "supply-chain-pressure/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "SupplyChainPressure", action = "results" }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing . I do the same config. But it still doesnt work-          routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SupplyChainPressureResult",
                url: "supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult/{resultid}",
                defaults: new { controller = "SupplyChainPressure", action = "ScptResult" }
                );

Comment: You need to place that route above the `Default` route. Does that help?